# How do I dynamically change input cell in a formula based on the value in another cell in a spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, cell, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

It is possible to dynamically change the input cell address in a formula based on the content in another cell?

Let's say I have a spreadsheet (excel or libreoffice) with these cell values:

```
A1: 10
A5:  9
C1:  5
```

Instead of hardcoding `=A1-A5` , I would like to do something like this: `=A1-A(C1)`, that would be evaluated at run time to use cell `A5` for the second input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDIRECT to take the value in C1 as a pointer to the row that you want in column A:-

```
=A1-INDIRECT("A"&C1)
```

(tested in Open Office and Excel 2010)

Answer (score 4):

The non-volatile¹ solution would be the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a).

```
'for Excel
=A1-INDEX(A:A, C1)
'for OpenOffice
=A1-INDEX(A$1:A$1048576; C1)
```

[image: nonvolatile_index]
[image: nonvolatile_index_oo]

---

¹ <sub>Volatile functions recalculate whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that affects their outcome changes. Examples of **volatile** functions are [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd), [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592), [TODAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566), [NOW](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NOW-function-3337FD29-145A-4347-B2E6-20C904739C46), [RAND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RAND-function-4CBFA695-8869-4788-8D90-021EA9F5BE73) and [RANDBETWEEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685). Some sub-functions of the [CELL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) and [INFO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INFO-function-725f259a-0e4b-49b3-8b52-58815c69acae) worksheet functions will make them volatile as well.</sub>

Comment: Yes I just noticed that it need the second form of the range when I tried it in Open Office.

Comment: Thanks, Tom. My OO is a little outdated (it told me to update as soon as I opened it) but the image should demonstrate the difference in formula.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of dynamic reference, you need the `INDIRECT` function. It takes two arguments `INDIRECT(reference,style)`

**reference**, a text string containing a cell, a range of cells text or a named range

and **style** a boolean that if omitted or TRUE, indicates that reference is A1 style, and when FALSE, the reference is using the R1C1 style.

so in your case you can use

```
INDIRECT("A"&C1)
```

or

```
INDIRECT("R1C"&C1,FALSE)
```